# how to add the SFTP protocol to the alfresco application

Tags: sftp, alfresco

how to add the SFTP protocol to the alfresco application..presently alfresco running on CIFS, webdav,FTP & FTPS..

How can i connect to SFTP protocol by using alfresco...

Can any one please provide steps..................

Regards,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this JIRA enhancement https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-4488.

According to that it's available in Alfresco 3.4.0.

Comment: Although the issue says that it is available but they have implemented FTPS only instead of SFTP. The ticket title is actually confusing which leads the users into believing that DFTP is supported but it is not.

Comment: It looks like the requirement for ALF-4488 was some form of Secured FTP, and FTPS won out over SFTP for ease of implementing. If you wanted to do real SFTP (ssh based), you'd need to look at Apache Mina (as discussed in that ticket)